# onClick Window.Location does not work in Chromium (Linux version of Google Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, linux, google-chrome, chromium

I think I'm being silly or something, but I can't seem to get my onClick to work through Chromium, which is a Linux version of Chrome (FireFox is fine, as is IE)

Here's some HTML code:

```
<form>
<select name="month">
<option value="1" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='<SOMEPAGE>'; return false;">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that using onClick on option elements is not supported on all browsers. Even if it is then there are still probably better ways of doing it.

How about using the onChange event of the select and then checking to see which option has been selected. It's then very easy to add cases for other options without your html getting messy.

e.g.

```
<form>

<script language="JavaScript">
function doSomething() {
    selected=document.getElementById("month")[document.getElementById("month").selectedIndex].value;
    switch(selected) {
    case "1":
        window.location.href='http://www.ibm.com';
        break;
        }
    }
</script>

<select name="month" id="month" onChange="doSomething()">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with window.open() method?

Replace:

```
<option value="1" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='<SOMEPAGE>'; return false;">January</option>
```

by

```
<option value="1" onclick="window.open('<SOMEPAGE>')">January</option>
```

Comment: Yes. I tried "window.open()" Again, Firefox liked it, but Chrome/Chromium didn't do anything

Comment: Is it the latest version of Chromium? Did Chrome have the same issue? Which linux distribution do you use? Is it on mobile (Android, IOS)?

Comment: Browser Type: Chromium 37.0.2062.120

Linux Distribution: Ubuntu 14.04

No, this isn't mobile.

Chrome seems to have the same issue as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Use onchange event instead then get the selected value with JQuery.
Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
function openWindow(){
    if($("#mySelect option:selected").text() === 'January')
        window.open('<SOMEPAGE>');
}
</script>

<form>
<select id="mySelect" name="month" onchange="openWindow()">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
<option value="3">March</option>
<option value="4">April</option>
<option value="5">May</option>
<option value="6">June</option>
<option value="7">July</option>
<option value="8">August</option>
<option value="9">September</option>
<option value="10">October</option>
<option value="11">November</option>
<option value="12">December</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer does it work? do Chrome show a message when he block the window.open?

Comment: No, No, Definitely Not. This even broke the layout of the page as well as Firefox's working version and STILL didn't fix Chrome/Chromium issue