# Form event onChange not working on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, forms

I have one form that works perfectly and changes the action of the form based on radio buttons:

```
 <form name="form1" method="post" action="[[base_urlnt]]/electricity-rate-plans">
 <input type="radio" name="energy" value="electricity" checked>
 <label for="electricity">Electricity</label>
 <input type="radio" name="energy" value="gas" onChange="if(this.checked){document.forms[0].action='[[base_urlnt]]/natural-gas-rate-plans'}">
 <label for="gas">Natural Gas</label>
 <input name="service_zip_5" type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter ZIP Code"><button type="submit" class="bigButton">Get Rates</button>
 </form>
```

And I want to do the same thing, but change the action on another form by using onChange but not on radio buttons, but using a dropdown list seen below. What am I doing wrong?

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="[[base_url]]alberta/electricity-plans">
<p>Choose Your Service</p>
<select name="service" id="service" title="Choose Your Service">
<option value="Electricity" selected="selected">Electricity</option>
<option value="Gas" onChange="if(this.selected){document.forms[0].action='[[base_url]]alberta/natural-gas-plans'}">Natural Gas</option>
<option value="Dual" onChange="if(this.selected){document.forms[0].action='[[base_url]]alberta/dual-fuel-plans'}">Dual Fuel</option>
</select>
<p>Enter Your ZIP Code</p>
<input name="service_zip_5" type="text" id="zipcode">
<button type="submit" id="submit">Get Started</button>
</form>
```

I tried 
    onChange="if(this.checked)
first and the thought that since it is a selection it should be onChange="if(this.selected) but neither work. Is this just not a function?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423993/onclick-window-location-does-not-work-in-chromium-linux-version-of-google-chrom/26425189#26425189) is a link to an answer that I gave to a similar question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change it slightly.

Your onchange events should be bound to the select not the individual options.

I have also added an attribute "data-url" to each option to store the url that will need to be added to the form action onchange.

This "data-url" attribute can then be used by the javascript function to update the form action. It also means you don't have to repeat the same code in all of your onchange attributes. You can just call a function that extracts the corresponding "data-url".

See - http://jsfiddle.net/williamtdavies/8kxzaquw/

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="[[base_url]]alberta/electricity-plans">
    <p>Choose Your Service</p>
    <select name="service" id="service" title="Choose Your Service" onChange="changeFormAction(this);">
        <option value="Electricity" data-url="[[base_url]]alberta/electricity-plans">Electricity</option>
        <option value="Gas" data-url="[[base_url]]alberta/natural-gas-plans">Natural Gas</option>
        <option value="Dual" data-url="[[base_url]]alberta/dual-fuel-plans">Dual Fuel</option>
    </select>
    <p>Enter Your ZIP Code</p>
    <input name="service_zip_5" type="text" id="zipcode"/>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Get Started</button>
</form>

<script>
    function changeFormAction(elem){
    document.forms[0].action = elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].getAttribute("data-url"); 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It still keeps taking me to the default electricity page, is that because in the  form action it still has that and needs to be changed to something else?

Comment: I have updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/williamtdavies/8kxzaquw/) to include an alert of the form action so that you can see what the current action is when the form is submitted. If you can setup a jsfiddle with your latest code I may be able to help but at the moment out of context this is doing what you need.

Comment: It is something on my cms where it is ignoring the JS, something I will have to work out. Thanks!

Comment: Could it be that there are multiple forms on the page and the JS is not directly tied to this form (even though I have the JS immediately after the form)? If so, is there a way to tie this form to this js?

Comment: It could be that. If you view the source of the page and find more than one form element on the page. You will need to look for some sort of identifier / add a new identifier to the form you want to update.